# SAS proc export without comma thousands

Tags: sas

I noticed in the SAS log that when I call a `proc export data=mydata outfile="csv.csv" dbms=csv replace; run;`, I get a generated internal set which declares a comma data format: `comma20.3`.

```
138         format YEAR best12. ;
145         format RATE_SPREAD comma20.3 ;
```

How can I get `proc export` not to do this, and to export without comma separators? Eg `9000` instead of `9,000`?

Comment: What's the format of the variable on the SAS dataset?

Comment: Change the format to be one that doesn't have a comma. When it creates the file it will embed that column in quotes so that it can be read cleanly by other systems, though they may recognize it as a character instead of numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately PROC EXPORT does not support the FORMAT statement.

You could make a view to the original data with the format removed and export that.

```
data for_export / view=for_export;
  set mydata;
  format rate_spread ;
run;
proc export data=for_export outfile="csv.csv" dbms=csv replace;
run;
```

But you really don't need to use PROC EXPORT to write a CSV file.  A data step works just as well. You might have to do a little work to add the header row.

```
proc transpose data=mydata(obs=0) out=names ;
   var _all_;
run;
data _null_;
  file "csv.csv" dsd ;
  set names;
  put _name_ @;
run;
data _null_;
  file "csv.csv" dsd mod ;
  set mydata;
  put (_all_) (+0);
  format rate_spread ;
run;
```